# modify lists based on dates

Tags: r, list

Hello I have list in lists data

```
list1 <- list()

#date list is a "date" object
list1$date <- c("01/06/2002", "02/06/2002", "03/06/2002", 
"04/06/2002", "05/06/2002", "01/07/2002", "19/07/2002", "11/07/2002", 
               "15/07/2002", "17/07/2002", "03/07/2002")

list1$value1 <- c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200)

list1$value2 <- c(1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000)
```

I want to modify the values in the list such that if the dates are in between 1 and 7 - the list values get doubled.

Is there a way where I can write a condition that checks the day of the list and doubles the value in the other lists?

Expected Output:

```
 list$value1 
 c(200,400,600,200,400,600,100,200,300,100,400)
    
 list$value2 
 c(2000,4000,6000,2000,4000,6000,1000,2000,3000,1000,4000)
```

Comment: At the values in `list$date` Date objects or just a character vector?

Comment: its a date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the dates extracting first 2 characters and use `lapply` to double the values where the dates are between 1 and 7.

```
inds <- as.integer(substr(list1$date, 1, 2)) <= 7
#List names that needs to be changed
nm <- c('value1', 'value2')
list1[nm] <- lapply(list1[nm], function(x) {x[inds] <- x[inds] * 2;x})
list1

#$date
# [1] "01/06/2002" "02/06/2002" "03/06/2002" "04/06/2002" "05/06/2002" "01/07/2002"
# [7] "19/07/2002" "11/07/2002" "15/07/2002" "17/07/2002" "03/07/2002"

#$value1
# [1] 200 400 600 200 400 600 100 200 300 100 400

#$value2
# [1] 2000 4000 6000 2000 4000 6000 1000 2000 3000 1000 4000
```

**data**

There were some missing quotation in the data, fixing that and change the name of the list to `list1` since `list` is a name of the function.

```
list1 <- list()
list1$date <- c("01/06/2002", "02/06/2002", "03/06/2002", 
"04/06/2002", "05/06/2002", "01/07/2002", "19/07/2002", "11/07/2002", 
               "15/07/2002", "17/07/2002", "03/07/2002")

list1$value1 <- c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200)

list1$value2 <- c(1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000)
```

Comment: list1$date is a date object.  substr would not work right`?

Comment: The example does not show it as Date object. If so, then try using `inds <- as.integer(format(list1$date, '%d')) <= 7`

Comment: I also have another condition where the date should be greater than 28. I tried something like this `inds <- as.integer(format(list1$date, '%d')) <= 7 || as.integer(format(list1$date, '%d')) >= 28` but this is not working

Comment: Use `|` instead of `||` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the day using `as.numeric(strftime())`, and replace values conditionally with `ifelse()`:

```
for (val in c("value1", "value2")) {
  List[[val]] <- ifelse(
    as.numeric(strftime(List[["date"]], "%d")) <= 7,
    List[[val]] * 2,
    List[[val]]
  )
}

List[c("value1", "value2")]
```

```
$value1
 [1] 200 400 600 200 400 600 100 200 300 100 400

$value2
 [1] 2000 4000 6000 2000 4000 6000 1000 2000 3000 1000 4000
```